# Why does wget from ftp-sites sometimes create a few empty files when it downloads the rest of the files without problems?

Tags: linux, redhat, ftp, wget

I have downloaded 80.000+ image files stored on a FTP-site using wget(1) and most of the files where downloaded without problems but when I did a small check (using file(1)) I just realized that a few of the files were empty!?!

I just used this command:

```
wget -r -nH --user YYY --password ZZZ ftp://X.X.X.X
```

I would have expected the ftp transfer either to retry or/and eventually fail. Is this a bug in wget(1) og in the ftp-protocol?

I can see [others have the same problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91785/wget-grabbing-empty-files-that-actually-exist)!

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure why the files are empty but you can try 
`wget -c 'ftp://image-link'` with all the links it should re-download/resume corrupted files only.

Comment: That would (probably) work but I am scared about the fact that I cannot rely on wget/ftp to either get the file or fail!

Comment: Are you sure that it's wget issue maybe the files are corrupted on the FTP server?

Comment: The site owner tells me that he has the files - but yes that is a possibility! :-|

Comment: Do you store a log of the wget actions with `wget --append-output=logfile`?

Comment: Well no - the log would be so big that I would not know what to look for - but a good suggestion anyway.